# Hibernate Duplicate Entry exception creates Lock on row in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, database-deadlocks

Using MySQL and Hibernate 4.3.5

I have a row in `Mortgage` table with primary key `091210`. In Java app using hibernate, when I (wrongly) try to save a mortgage with same key, proper `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '091210' for key 'PRIMARY'` exception is logged, *not thrown*.

Problem:

**This exception is is thrown/logged yet the program does not complete execution nor terminate. Further, I notice an update/delete lock is created on the original row which caused the duplicate exception**. The only way to recover is if I can manually terminate program, and then the orignial row is no longer "locked"

- Is this expected, has any one experienced this before?
- How can this be recovered from in the Java program?

I hoped that this sort of exception would cancel / break the transaction, and then exception would be thrown. But instead, seems exception is only logged, a lock is created on DB, and the process seems to just hang at `transaction.commit()`...

Code:

```
System.out.println("Begin transaction");
session.beginTransaction();

System.out.println("Save mortgage");
session.save(mortgage);
System.out.println("Commit transaction");
session.getTransaction().commit();

System.out.println("Close session");
session.close();
System.out.println("Close SessionFactory");
HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
```

Relevant output I see:

```
Begin transaction
Save mortgage
Commit transaction
Hibernate: insert into mortgage (address, last_name, inst_id, date, mortgage_num) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Mar 30, 2015 7:59:54 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
```

... 
`Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '091210' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Then the program just hangs, still running with red light glowing, and the lock on the DB.

There's no `try-catch`, no logging. This is from the Eclipse console.

Comment: I assume you catch the exception and then write it into the log file. When you catch it, do you do a rollback of the hibernate transaction? Because that should fix the lock.

Comment: My app wasn't doing any logging, and had no `try-catch`. I'll update answer with the code I executed.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it some more tomorrow at work then, if I can find a spare 15 minutes or so.

Comment: Help me @Ractoc , you're my only hope ;)

Answer (score 0):

Let me put the answer here so I can properly format the code...

In your code, add a bit of error handling:

```
try {
    System.out.println("Begin transaction");
    session.beginTransaction();

    System.out.println("Save mortgage");
    session.save(mortgage);
    System.out.println("Commit transaction");
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    System.out.println("Close session");
    session.close();
    System.out.println("Close SessionFactory");
    HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
} catch (HibernateException he) {
    he.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will print the entire stacktrace to you console. There are better ways of logging stuff like this, but for not this will do nicely. When you end up in the catch, you might also want to do a nice rollback of the transaction. But that kind of cleanup can come after we fix your more immediate problem.

I'll be putting up a nice tutorial over the next few days if you want.

Comment: as mentioned in Q above, there's no catching or anything of exceptions. That was why this was so odd. No exception is thrown/caught. The program just hanged there. I didn't have any catch statements, so anything being thrown should have terminated the program. And the logs from hibernate showed up not because I was doing any logging, but because Eclipse was just putting hibernate's own logging to the console window